# column name will cut by underscore

Tags: java, spring-boot

I recently using this class to constrct pageable object.

```
new PageRequest(page, length, Direction.DESC, 'ad_id');
```

However, error shows:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property ad found for type Advertisement! Did you mean 'adId'?] with root cause
```

It seems that the underscore cut the `_id` part and left `ad` as property, thus the property can't be find in real database colunm.

Is there any naming limit or something else which need to be taken care when giving name to a column.

I choose to remame the property name for a temporary solution.

Comment: shouldn't you provide an entity field there ? I mean if you have column `user_name` , you can have entity's filed called `userName` mapped to that column  and that's what should be put there.

Comment: @john yes, I now do the same thing as you said. But what if I have the entity's filed still called `user_name`(I know it may be unreasonabel), the error still exits, so I wonder if the underscore is special case.

Comment: not sure about that. maybe Spring treats it in some special way, but that's why we have something called code convention (camelCase, etc.)))